# Can Google-ads be placed in a carousel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, adsense

I am currently trying to ad 2 Google-ads to a Rails project using bootstraps carousel. The first ad displays fine but the second ad does not show up in the carousel.

I have tested that the ads render fine when stacked on top of each other. I have also tested the carousel is working correctly and is outputting simple text.

Am I right to assume the second ad will not show up because it renders in the same location as the first ad

**HTML**

```
<div id="carousel-signup" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators carousel-indicators-numbers">
      <li data-target="#carousel-signup" data-slide-to="0" class="active">1</li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-signup" data-slide-to="1">2</li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-signup" data-slide-to="2">3</li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-signup" data-slide-to="3">4</li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-signup" data-slide-to="4">5</li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-signup" data-slide-to="5">6</li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div class="control-label">First Name:</div>
          <div class="field-wrapper">
            <%= f.input_field :first_name, placeholder: "First name", class: "input-lg", autofocus: true, tabindex: 1 %>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <a class="next btn" tabindex="2">Continue</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="adsense">
          <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
          <!-- FRT | SimplyJobs (Placement 2) -->
          <ins class="adsbygoogle"
               style="display:block"
               data-ad-client="ca-pub-123"
               data-ad-slot="123"
               data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
          <script>
          (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
          </script>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div class="control-label">Last Name:</div>
          <div class="field-wrapper">
            <%= f.input_field :last_name, placeholder: "Last name", class: "input-lg", tabindex: 3 %>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <a class="next btn" tabindex="4">Continue</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="adsense">
          <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
          <!-- FRT | SimplyJobs (Placement 2) -->
          <ins class="adsbygoogle"
               style="display:block"
               data-ad-client="ca-pub-123"
               data-ad-slot="123"
               data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
          <script>
          (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
          </script>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div class="control-label">Street Address:</div>
          <div class="field-wrapper">
            <%= f.input_field :address1, placeholder: "e.g. 123 Main Street", class: "input-lg", tabindex: 5 %>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <a class="next btn" tabindex="6">Continue</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div class="control-label">Zipcode:</div>
          <div class="field-wrapper">
            <%= f.input_field :postal, value: client_postal_code(resource), placeholder: "Zipcode", class: "input-lg", type: "number", tabindex: 7 %>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <a class="next btn" tabindex="8">Continue</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div class="control-label">Email:</div>
          <div class="field-wrapper">
            <%= f.input_field :email, placeholder: "Email address", class: "input-lg", tabindex: 9 %>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <a class="next btn" tabindex="10">Continue</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div class="control-label">Phone:</div>
          <div class="field-wrapper">
            <%= f.input_field :phone, placeholder: "Phone number", class: "input-lg", tabindex: 11 %>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <p class="disclaimer">
              * By completing and submitting this form, I agree to be contacted by Simply Jobs at the email and phone (including my wireless) number provided regarding Job Openings. I understand that these calls may be generated using an autodialer and may also contain pre-recorded messages. To receive this information without providing consent, <%= link_to "skip here", "/jobs", id: "deny-consent" %>. By clicking GET STARTED &amp; APPLY, I certify that I am a U.S. Resident over the age of 18, and I agree to the <%= link_to "Privacy Policy", privacy_policy_path %> and <%= link_to "Terms & Conditions", terms_path %>.
            </p>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <button class="next btn" tabindex="12">Get Started &amp; Apply</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is this even allowed by their policy?

Comment: I have been confirmed that this is not possible and more than likely against policy.

Comment: Might want to throw this in as an answer as I'm sure you're not the only person who's thought to try this.

Comment: The problem is actually the "active" class being called in the first div containing the "item" class. Moving the "active" class to the second carousel item allowed the ad to be rendered, though it doesnt fix the problem as only one ad can be viewed at a time.

Comment: Are there other ads on the page outside of carousel? Anyways - you might be hitting one of few limitations: more than 3 ad blocks per page, more than one "large" ad unit per page and  "embedding the ad code in excessive div tags or nested frames.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not allowed by Google's Adsense Terms of Services

https://www.google.com/adsense/terms